# Utility Objects Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, cron, bundle, wamp

I have tried to get started with symfony 2 several times but have always gotten stuck along the way. This time I plan on sticking with it!

So far my biggest question is where to put Objects that will carry out tasks without the user interaction.

Ex.

I want to create a few php classes which will handle parsing some data from several websites every day or so.  I want this task to be launched either manually or via a cron job. As such I  only really need the model and controller I guess. (Controller to parse the site and create a model, model to store parsed data and persist to db ).  Is the best way to go about doing this to create a bundle that deals solely with these background jobs.

I am thinking about the following classes:

- SiteParser

  - Site1Parser Extends SiteParser
  - Site2Parser Extends SiteParser
- Model1
- Model2
- Some Class in charge of orchestrating the parsing of different sites and telling the created models to persist.

Does that seem logical?  And if so how would I go about putting that structure into symfony?

Thanks for any and all help, if I haven't been clear or you have a question please ask I will provide any details needed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'd advise against using a Controller here. Remember that the purpose of a Controller is to mediate between the model and the view. With automated processes, you don't really have a view -- nobody's looking at or reading your output (you may want to implement some logging, but that's another matter).

That said, I'd say that your best bet is to create a command using Symfony's built-in Console Command feature. You've probably used the `app/console` command tool to do things like generate bundles and create entity mappings. With the `ContainerAwareCommand` class, you can actually write your own. And the best part is that the command knows about the container... in other words, you can access Doctrine, Monolog, Twig, or any of the other services directly, using a `get()` method.

So let's suppose that your application extracts images from the site, and then saves the URLs of those images into a database. To do this, you first need to create a service class (let's put it under the MyBundle\Service namespace), and give it the necessary methods:

```
namespace MyBundle\Service;

class Parser
{    
    public function extractImageUrls($siteUrl)
    {
        // Do whatever here, and return an array of URLs
    }
}
```

Then you can register it as a service named "parser" through app/config/config.yml:

```
services:
    parser:
        class: MyBundle\Service\Parser
```

Now, you can call `get("parser")` from your container. Controllers extend the container, so in a controller you can say `$this->get("parser")`, but in your Console Command you have to specifically get the container: `$this->getContainer()->get("parser")`.

So then you can write your SiteParseCommand to look something like this:

```
namespace MyBundle\Command;

class SiteParseCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName("site:parse");
        $this->addArgument("site", InputArgument::REQUIRED);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $parser = $this->getContainer()->get("parser");
        $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine");
        $em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
        $imageRepository = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Image");

        $site = $input->getArgument("site");

        $images = $parser->getImageUrls($site);

        // Add each image to the database as you normally would, using your entity manager
    }
}
```

Now, from the command line, you can call:

```
app/console site:parse "http://url.com"
```

Add that to crontab, and I think you're good to go.

Again, since there's no view, you're not going to be able to easily tell if everything is working properly. So I'd implement some sort of logging to let you know what's going on. Since Monolog is also a service, the Console Command has access to it as well, via `$this->getContainer()->get("logger")`.

Hope this helps!

(More documentation on the ContainerAwareCommand class [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html))

Comment: Thank you so much! Awesome answer that really clears up a lot of confusion I have had in the past. I will look into all that you wrote in more detail tomorrow but I think that you have set me on the right track!